# Decoupling a double integral

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, integration

I came across this question while making some calculations.

> **QUESTION.** Can you find some transformation to "decouple" the double integral as follows?
> $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{d\alpha\,d\beta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta}}
> =\frac14\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\cos\theta\,\sin\theta}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{d\omega}{\sqrt{\cos\omega\,\sin\omega}}.$$

Comment: Do you know that the equality you cite is true?

Comment: @LSpice: that I know is true, yes.

Comment: for the record, this integral equals $(16/\pi) \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^4$.

Comment: The second integral is a period of $E^2 = E\times E$ where $E$ is the 
CM elliptic curve $Y^2 = X^3 - X$.  The first is a period of the K3 surface
$S: z^2 = xy(1-x)(1-y)(1-xy)$ (using **Iosif Pinelis**'s transformation).
It turns out that $S$ is the Kummer surface of $E^2$, i.e. the K3 surface
birational to $E^2 / \{\pm 1\}$.  One can thus find an explicit birational
transformation, though it may take some work.
How does this arise in your research?

Comment: if I input the double integral on the left-hand-side into Mathematica it evaluates it as $K(1/2)^2$, which is the integral squared on the right-hand-side, so I would think that the decoupling transformation should be a quick application of a known transformation rule for elliptic integrals; now if only I could ask Mathematica to disclose the intermediate steps...

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: thank you for the interpretations. I was computing some infinite integrals which after a bit of work got transformed to into the LHS as trig integrals. The RHS is some "leap of faith".

Comment: Perform the change of variable $\sin(u)=\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$ and recall that: $\sin^2(a)-\sin^2(b)=\sin(a-b)\sin(a+b)$ (i wish i had find out this trick)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Thanks go to Etanche and Jandri)
\begin{align}J&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2 \varphi}}d\varphi d\theta\\
 &\overset{z\left(\varphi\right)=\arcsin\left(\sin(\theta)\sin \varphi\right)}=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_0^ \theta\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(\theta-z)\sin(\theta+ z)}}dz\right)d\theta\tag1\\
 &=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_{u}^{\pi-u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dv\right)du \tag2\\
 &=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_{u}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dv\right)du+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi-u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dv\right)du}_{w=\pi-v}\\
 &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_{u}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dv\right)du\\
&\overset{u\longleftrightarrow v}=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_{0}^{u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dv\right)du\\
 &=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin u\sin v}}dudv}
 \end{align}

and to obtain the form in the OP, finally substitute $u=2\theta $, $v=2\omega $.

$(1)$: $\displaystyle dz=\dfrac{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta-\sin^2 z}}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 z}}d\varphi$, $\sin^2 a-\sin^2 b=\sin(a-b)\sin(a+b)$

$(2)$: Change of variable $u=\theta-z,v=\theta+z$

Answer (score 8):

$\newcommand\al\alpha\newcommand\be\beta\newcommand\th\theta\newcommand\om\omega$Making substitutions $\sin^2\al=x$, $\sin^2\be=y$, $\sin2\th=s$, and $\sin2\om=t$, we rewrite the equality in question in the following "algebraic" way:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dx\,dy}{\sqrt{xy(1-x)(1-y)(1-xy)}}
=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{2ds\,dt}{\sqrt{st(1-s)(1-t)(1+s)(1+t)}}.$$
Perhaps this could help, especially because the integrands on the left and on the right now look "more similar" to each other than in the original setting.

---

**A further comment:** The main difficulty here appears to be with the integral, say $L$, on the left. Expanding $\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-xy}}$ in powers of $xy$:
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-xy}}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mx^my^m$$
with $a_m:=(-1)^m\binom{-1/2}m$ and using the expression of the beta function in terms of the gamma function, we have
$$L=\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m\Big(\int_0^1 dx\, x^{m-1/2}(1-x)^{-1/2}\Big)^2
=\frac{\pi^2}4\,N,$$
where
$$N:=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac1{4^{3m}}\,\binom{2m}m^3.$$
According to Mathematica,
$$N=\frac\pi{\Gamma(3/4)^4}=1.393203929\ldots\quad\text{and hence}\quad L=\frac{\pi^3}{4\Gamma(3/4)^4};$$
however, I do not know how Mathematica does this.

One may also note that $N$ is the expected number of times a symmetric simple random walk on $\mathbb Z^3$ visits its starting point. That is,
$$N=\sum_{m=0}^\infty P(X_{2m}=Y_{2m}=Z_{2m}=0)
=E\sum_{m=0}^\infty 1(X_{2m}=Y_{2m}=Z_{2m}=0),$$
where $X_n:=R_1+\cdots+R_n$, the $R_i$'s are iid Rademacher random variables (with $P(R_i=\pm1)=1/2$), and $(Y_n)$ and $(Z_n)$ are iid copies of $(X_n)$.
It seems amusing that, whereas the dimension $3$ of $\mathbb Z^3$ is odd, $N$ is the square of a certain nice expression.

Closely related to $N$ is [Pólya's random walk constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html), equal $1-1/N$, which is the probability that the random walk will ever return to its starting point.

The equality
$$N=\frac\pi{\Gamma(3/4)^4}=1.393203929\ldots$$
seems to be proved by [Montroll, formulas (6.11), (6.12), (6.1)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2098789).

Comment: I have added a further comment to the answer.

Comment: I appreciate your transformation and the added (useful) information.

Comment: This equality of algebraic integrals resembles  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103054/equating-the-integrals-of-1-1-xy-and-2-1xy-by-elementary-calculus -- can a similar technique work here?

Comment: @MattF. : Thank you for this interesting reference. Unfortunately, at this point I don't see how that technique can be used here, because here $1-xy$ is under the square root.

Answer (score 8):

It might help to put the question in a bit broader perspective. Elliptic integrals provide a variety of such "decoupling" expressions, as listed in 
[Definite Integrals of the Complete Elliptic Integral](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/80B/jresv80Bn2p313_A1b.pdf).

For example, the following identity holds for any $z>$1,
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{d\alpha\,d\beta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta}}\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sqrt{z^2-\sin^2\alpha}}
=\left(\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{z+\cos 2\theta}}\right)^2,\qquad(1)$$
and there is a similar expression for $0<z<1$.

There are also closed form expressions for double integrals that include the one in the OP (for $s=1$),
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^{s-1}2\alpha\;d\alpha\,d\beta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta}}=\left(\frac{\pi\Gamma(s/2)}{2\Gamma(3/4)\Gamma(s/2+1/4)}\right)^2,\;\;{\rm Re}\,s>0.\qquad (2)$$

For $s=1$ the right-hand-side equals $K(1/2)^2$, and it might be interesting to see if there is a more general expression in terms of the square of an elliptic integral (perhaps by evaluating $K$ at one of the [elliptic singular values](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html), when  the complete elliptic integrals may be computed in analytic form in terms of gamma functions).

---

Following Iosif Pinelis's suggestion, the last integral can be worked out by substituting the series expansion of the elliptic integral (and transforming to $u=\sin\alpha$)
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^{s-1}2\alpha\;d\alpha\,d\beta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta}}=2^{s-1}\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)^2\int_{0}^1 u^{2 n} u^{s-1} \left(1-u^2\right)^{\frac{s}{2}-1}\,du$$
$$\qquad=2^{s-3}\Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2  \Gamma \left(n+\frac{s}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (n+1)^2 \Gamma (n+s)}.\qquad (3)$$
Mathematica evaluates the sum over $n$ of the gamma functions to give the expression in formula 2. I don't know how Mathematica does it, and have asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/384355/11260) --- with several instructive answers!

Comment: Thank you for the relevant and instructive pointers.

Comment: A quick guess is that your second integral is based on formula (2) in Table I of the paper by Glasser you referred to; is this so? Glasser writes that formulas "such as (1-18) were obtained quite simply by integrating the series representing $\mathbf K(u)$ term by term." I guess, at least for $s=1$ this reduces to the evaluation of the series in the definition of $N$ in my answer. I am no specialist in these matters, but the evaluation of that series does not seem trivial to me. Is it indeed "quite simpl[e]"?

Comment: yes, indeed, the second integral is formula 2; the first integral is formula 11; I have worked out the series expansion, the sum over Gamma functions does not look too complicated, I might ask separately on MO.